# Can we load and display uninstalled Fonts in LINQpad?

Tags: wpf, xaml, svg, fonts, linqpad

After loading my PCL DLL under **Additional References** in LINQpad, I've tried two different techniques to load and display fonts. The first is the most straight forward:

```
var xaml = @"
<UserControl
    xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
    <TextBox
        FontFamily=""/Songhay.Portable.Resources;Component/Fonts/#FontAwesome""
        FontSize=""64""
        Text=""&#xf09b;""
        />
</UserControl>
";

var control = (UserControl)XamlReader.Parse(xaml);
control.Dump();
```

The XAML declarations above work quite fine in WPF proper but LINQpad displays the blank square. So I tried the more explicit route:

```
var dll = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Songhay.Portable.Resources.ResourceModule));
dll.GetManifestResourceNames().Dump();

var resourceName = dll.GetManifestResourceNames().First(i => i.EndsWith("FontAwesome.otf"));
using (var stream = dll.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
{
    var localData = new PrivateFontCollection();
    var fontdata = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(fontdata, 0, (int)stream.Length);
    unsafe
    {
        fixed(byte * pFontData = fontdata)
        {
            localData.AddMemoryFont((System.IntPtr)pFontData, fontdata.Length);
        }
    }
    localData.Dump();

    var textBox = new TextBox
    {
        FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily(localData.Families.First().Name),
        FontSize = 64,
        Text = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#xf09b;")
    };
    textBox.Dump();
}
```

Same issue: blank square. Too much of an edge case for LINQpad?

Solving this problem, by the way, would make LINQpad a very powerful design tool---an informal sketch pad outside of the ceremony of Blend/Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the SVG web font format and the XAML `Path` element:

```
var path = @"..\font-awesome-4.2.0\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.svg";
//You cannot stop .NET from condensing entities so load as string:
var xml = File.ReadAllText(path).Replace("unicode=\"&#", "unicode=\"&amp;#");
var fontAwesomeSvg = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer
{
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Azure),
    Padding = new Thickness(4),
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible,
    Width = 960, Height = 600
};
var wrapPanel = new WrapPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };

scrollViewer.Content = wrapPanel;

XNamespace svg = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
fontAwesomeSvg.Descendants(svg+"glyph")
    .ToList().ForEach(i =>
    {
        var d = i.ToAttributeValueOrDefault("d", string.Empty);
        var unicode = i.Attribute("unicode").Value;
        var xaml = @"
        <Grid xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
            Margin=""4"">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox
                Background=""Transparent""
                BorderThickness=""0""
                HorizontalContentAlignment=""Center""
                Text=""{Binding EntityDisplayText, Mode=OneWay}""
                />
            <Border Grid.Row=""1""
                BorderThickness=""2"" BorderBrush=""DarkGray""
                MinHeight=""96"" Padding=""4""
                Width=""96"" Height=""Auto"">
                <Path
                    Data=""{Binding StreamGeometry, Mode=OneWay}""
                    Fill=""Black""
                    RenderTransformOrigin=""0.5,0.5""
                    Stretch=""Uniform"">
                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY=""-1"" />
                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                </Path>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
        ";
        var control = (Grid)XamlReader.Parse(xaml);
        control.DataContext = new
        {
            StreamGeometry = d,
            EntityDisplayText = unicode
        };
        wrapPanel.Children.Add(control);
    });

scrollViewer.Dump();
```

One caveat: the `d` attribute of the SVG `glyph` or `path` does not map perfectly to the XAML `Path` (note how `Path.RenderTransform` is used).